# Android: how to consolidate two strings.xml into one

Tags: android, string, resources

I have two strings.xml files, say strings_1.xml and strings_2.xml which are both android resource files. Now I want to consolidate these strings into a single strings.xml, for duplicates, strings_1.xml will be the master. Is there any existing tool that can do the work easily?

Comment: Considered: copy -> paste -> delete duplicates -> save as "strings_1.xml"?

Comment: Try doing that with WinMerge for example. You can merge them both with this tool, see here: http://winmerge.org/

Comment: You may write a small Java program which would parse your xml files and use the `Set` structure which will combine their contents in one and put into the new xml :)